# How to find what values of $a$ make $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=ax$ if $x<0$ continuous and differentiable at 0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2, \text{ if } x\geq 0\\ ax, \text{ if } x<0\end{cases}$

(a) For which values of $a$ is $f$ differentiable at $x=0$?

(b) For which values of $a$ is $f$ continuous at $x=0$?

(c) When $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, does $f^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exist?

Here is the function as $a$ goes from $-10$ to $10$.
[image: function]

Here is my attempt:

(a) $a$ is differentiable at $x=0$ for only $a=0$. This is because the transition between the function pieces is "smooth". Though, I am also thinking, $a$ is differentiable at $x=0$ for all $a\geq 0$ because near $x=0$, $ax$ would behave similarly to $x^2$.

(b) The graph shows it is continuous everywhere for all $a$. I am unsure how to prove this though because we don't have $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $a$ at $x=0$.

(c) I am unsure about this one. I want to say no because there may be a jump in the slopes of the tangent lines if $a\ne0$. However, if the answer to (a) is $a=0$, then it would be a smooth transition and the tangent lines' slopes would be smooth transitions too.

Comment: You are (almost) correct each time. (For (a) your first thought is right,) To verify your intuition by writing proofs, try going back to the defnitions of continuity and differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a)$ $Rf'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x=0$ and $Lf'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\frac{ax}{x}=a$

$f$ is differentiable if $Rf'(0)=Lf'(0)$,i.e., $a=0$

$(b)$ $Rf'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x^2 =0$ and $Lf'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^{-}}ax=0$

$f$ is continuous.

$(c)$ $Rf''(0)=2$ and $Lf''(0)=0$

$f$ is not twice differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's only when $a=0$. That's because that's the only case in which$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x.$$
2. For any $a$, we have$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=0=f(0).$$So, your answer is correct.
3. No, because $f$ is differentiable at $0$ only when $a=0$ and, in that case, the right derivative of $f'$ at $0$ is different from the left derivative. Therefore, $f''(0)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For point (a) you can compute the derivatives: for $x\geq0$ the derivative of $f$ is $f'(x)=2x$ and for $x<0$ is $f'(x)=a$. To say that $f$ is differentiable at the origin, you need that
$$ 
a=\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=0
$$
So only $a=0$ works. 
For point (b) the technique is the same, but you only need to check the limit of the function (not the derivative)
$$
0=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0
$$
So continuity holds for every $a$.
For point (c) you know that $f$ is differentiable iff $a=0$, so the function you are considering is $0$ for $x<0$ and $x^2$ for $x\geq 0$. Computing the second derivatives you obtain $f''(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f''(x)=2$ for $x\geq 0$, hence you have 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f''(x)=0\ne2=\lim_{x\to0^+}f''(x)
$$
So $f$ is not differentiable two times in $x=0$.